# bootstrap 3.1.1 collapse close on clicking outside

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a twitter bootstrap 3.1.1 app with a bootstrap inside.

```
<ul class="goods-categories goods-list">
  <div id="point" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#all" class="point blue m-top">Все товары</div>
  <div id="all" class="collapse">
    <li><a href="/products?category_id=11">Бумажная продукция</a>
    <li><a href="/products?category_id=14">Бумага для заметок, диспенсеры</a></li>
    <li><a href="/products?category_id=13">Блокноты, тетради</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

How can I make collapse closing when user clicks outside `#all` & it childs?

Comment: please add a fiddle of what you tried.

Comment: Rider, how can I add a fiddle if I don't know how to do it?

Comment: Hey asiniy you can add a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ . Using this we can replicate your issue and solve for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods provided by bootstrap collapse to manually show/hide the collapsible items. For your case it should work:

```
$('body *').not('.goods-categories.goods-list, .goods-categories.goods-list *').click(function() {
  $('#all').collapse('hide');
});
```

In this code above I am trying to bind the click event to body except the list and its children. And on click anywhere except the list I am hiding the collapsible item.

PS: I haven't tested it. But this should work with a bit of amendment.

Comment: All good except one thing: if I click to children, collapse closed.

Comment: Can you try removing this `, .goods-categories.goods-list *` part from not? If you can create a fiddle that would be great to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#all");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.removeClass('in');
    }
});
```